# Vscode not changing module version

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module

I'm using the python playsound module with a little app that I'm making, and it errors out if I use version 1.3.0, so I always use version 1.2.2, but I encountered a bug that caused me to uninstall and reinstall a few different versions. Eventually, I somehow managed to get vscode to think it has playsound 1.3.0 installed. And it errors now when I run it. But if I just run the raw file then it works perfectly fine.

Note: even when I uninstall the module it still tries to run in vscode, and the same 1.3.0 bug happens, the first note plays and then I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting VSCode. Sometimes it gets hung up. Whenever you install a new module, restart VSCode Becuase that normally fixes it.

Comment: already done that,  I've opened and closed vscode, refreshed the window, and refreshed my entire computer.

Comment: please put the output of this command `pip3 freeze` on pastebin (https://pastebin.com/). `pip3 freeze` list's all moduals and the version that you have

Comment: it says version 1.2.2 both on vscode and regular command prompt. When I try and run it on vscode, though, I get this error: ```The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.``` And when I just run it on regular command prompt it runs smoothly.

Comment: look over your program. I had an error like that and running it in the command prompt fixed it Becuase it was doing something to the file at run time.

Comment: I don't want to keep running it on command prompt, it works when I do. But vscode is still broken, plays a note then theres an error.

Comment: Maybe someone else can help you. I've run into a brick wall. Maybe posting your code in your quistion will help?